# jquery ui - cant seem to drag my draggables onto an empty sortable li

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have a list which I call #gallery in which I've defined a couple of li boxes.

e.g.

```
 <ul id="gallery">
   <li style="display: list-item; ui-draggable">A</li>
 </li>
```

and a box to drop them into ...

```
<div id="conditions-box" class="ui-droppable">      
    <ul class="gallery ui-helper-reset ui-sortable"></ul>    
</div>
```

With the following js

```
$('#conditions-box > ul').sortable();
$("#gallery > li").draggable({
   connectToSortable: '#conditions-box > ul',
   helper: 'clone'
});
```

When my conditions box list is empty as you see now I can drag the boxes in but they dont "stick" only when I place an existing li into the conditions box code does it actually work. However I dont want to have to do this. If you want a play you can see below. Any ideas ?

ref - http://jsfiddle.net/wmitchell/zCDE7/2/

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think you need to set `height` for your `conditions-box` sortable. You can use css like:

```
#conditions-box {
  height: 40px;
}
```

Comment: You put me onto the right answer it was actually the ul below that needed the height but yeah it now works ..

Comment: you saved me a lot of time and effort!

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the [dropOnEmpty](http://jqueryui.com/demos/sortable/#option-dropOnEmpty) option to the sortable, even though the default should be true, it doesn't appear to be working, because it works when the sortable is *not* empty.

Comment: as my earlier comment above - making the size of the target ul much larger fixed this for me.